# PHPHtmlParser getAttribute not works for custom attributes

Tags: php, domparser, getattribute

I have some HTML with custom attributes and trying to parse it with component PHPHtmlParser. Whole project created via this component. Here is the problem example given.

```
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
class Parsemydiv {
    function parseAttr()
    {
        $str='<div otop="20" oleft="20" name="info">
            <img src="example.jpg">
        </div>';
        $dom = new Dom();
        $dom->loadStr($str);
        $otop = $dom->getAttribute("otop");
        $name = $dom->getAttribute("name");
        echo "Name: " . $name  . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Top: " . $otop . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Left: " . $oleft . PHP_EOL;

    }
}
```

Output is:
Name: info
Top: 
Left:

getAttribute cannot get custom attributes.

Comment: If you want valid html you should use data-* attributes: `data-otop="20" data-oleft="20"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a 3rd party library to parse the DOM when PHP has built-in support for this? I suggest learning the [native functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead:

```
$str='<div otop="20" oleft="15" name="info">
        <img src="example.jpg">
    </div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$div = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
$otop = $div->getAttribute('otop');
$oleft = $div->getAttribute('oleft');

echo "otop=$otop, oleft=$oleft"; //otop=20, oleft=15
```